# How do you hide the status bar in cocoa touch?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, statusbar

I am making a video game for iPhone and I want to hide the status bar. It there any simple way to do so?

PD: I already tried to use the (projectName)info.plist file and there is no such property as status bar is initaly hidden as shown in the question [iPhone App - status bar hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029182/iphone-app-status-bar-hidden). Also, i am running xcode 4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```